# Dynamic templateUrl - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

So as of Angular 1.1.4, you can have a dynamic template url. From [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/partials/guide/directive.html),

> templateUrl - Same as template but the template is loaded from the specified  URL. Because the template loading is asynchronous the compilation/linking is suspended until the template is loaded.
>
> You can specify templateUrl as a string representing the URL or as a  function which takes two arguments tElement and tAttrs (described  in the compile function api below) and returns a string value representing  the url.

How can I utilize this to generate a dynamic template based on, say, an attribute on my directive? Obviously this doesn't work, since tAttrs.templateType is simply the string "templateType"

```
templateUrl: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
  if (tAttrs.templateType == 'search') {
    return '/b/js/vendor/angular-ui/template/typeahead/typeahead.html'
  } else {
    return '/b/js/vendor/angular-ui/template/typeahead/typeahead2.html'
  }
}
```

Given that I don't have access to the scope, how do I manage this?

Comment: As of Angular 1.2.17 (and possibly earlier), your original idea seems to work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The following is also possible for creating dynamic templates in AngularJS:
In your directive use:

```
template : '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>'
```

Now your controller may decide which template to use:

```
$scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
  return '/template/angular/search';
};
```

Because you have access to your scope parameters, you could also do:

```
$scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
  return '/template/angular/search/' + $scope.query;
};
```

So your server could create a dynamic template for you.

Comment: While this is an interesting, however, it seems to go against the grain of angular design, because it introduces a dependency between the directive and the controller which will dilute the encapsulation and standalone capability of the directive.

Comment: You could instead declare/assign the dynamic function inside of a `link:` property in the directive, since link can take a callback `function(scope, element, attrs)` that provides access to `scope`. This improves its ability to stand alone.

Answer (score 4):

```
templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
return attrs["template"] == "table" ?
"tableTemplate.html" : "itemTemplate.html";
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was with how I hacked the typeahead directive ... I was setting a scope variable on the typeahead, to be evaluated on the typeaheadPopup directive. Instead, I just passed the templateType attr directly as string & evaluated that. E.g.

```
var popUpEl = angular.element(
  "<typeahead-popup " +
    "matches='matches' " +
    "active='activeIdx' " +
    "select='select(activeIdx)' " +
    "template-type='" + attrs.templateType + "'" +
    "query='query' " +
    "position='position'>" +
  "</typeahead-popup>");
```

Instead of `"template-type='templateType'"`

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar issue when creating a file upload fallback for browsers that don't support the File API (< IE10). Key difference is I needed the page to intelligently decide which template to display without the benefit of an attribute value to switch on.

I ended up using the [constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) provider for my directive. Constants basically set up default parameters that can be injected anywhere in your directive. I simply let the constant call a function to determine browser support, then reference that value when I need to determine which template to pull. This is nice since **1)** there's no attribute to reference and **2)** it's available during the pre-link phase when you don't have access to the controller.

```
(function () {
  var myDir = angular.module('myDir', []);
  myDir.constant('myDirConfig', {
      hasFileSupport: fileApiIsSupported()
    });

  myDir.directive('myDir', ['myDirConfig', function (myDirConfig) {
      return {
          templateUrl: function () {
              if (myDirConfig.hasFileSupport) {
                  return 'pathToTemplate/html5.html';
              } else {
                  return 'pathToTemplate/fallback.html';
              }
          }
      };
  }];

  function fileApiIsSupported() { return (...); }
})();
```