# Dynamic `template` in AngularJS Directive for Table Row

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can I dynamically load an AngularJS Directive `templateUrl` when *working in a table*?

I have the following HTML, repeating a `tr` with a `fw-rule` directive:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="rule in data | orderBy:predicate:reverse" fw-rule="rule">
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like the contents of that `tr` to different, depending on the state of an "edit" variable.

One of my partials is below (the other is just a variation on layout):

```
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td ng-click="isEditing=!isEditing">{{ fwRule.name }}<br><span class="rule-description">{{ fwRule.description }}</span></td>
<td>{{ fwRule.source }}</td>
<td>{{ fwRule.destination }}</td>
<td>{{ fwRule.protocol }}</td>
<td>{{ fwRule.schedule }}</td>
<td>{{ fwRule.action }}</td>
<td>{{ fwRule.reporting }}</td>
```

I reviewed the following two questions here at SO, which almost gave me the answer:

- [Angular.js directive dynamic templateURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl)
- [Dynamic templateUrl - AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074454/dynamic-templateurl-angularjs)

However, they both call to write the directive's `template` using a `<div ng-include"getTemplateUrl()"></div>`, such are the following:

```
app.directive('fwRule', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      fwRule: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
        // a check would be made here to return the appropriate partial
        return 'partials/RuleEditTableRow.html'
      }
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>'
  };
});
```

This does not work in my case through, since `div` is not a valid child of `tr` (nor is `span`, which I also tried). As a result the browser renders that content outside the table.

Is there a way I can dynamically update the `template` of a directive, without using `ng-include`, so that it can behave inside a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $compile service to compile the correct template

```
app.directive('fwRule', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            fwRule: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {},
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            var template = '<td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td>';

            angular.element(element).html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())($scope);
        }
    };
});
```

I think I have it working with your code in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ztv5gwwx/4/